# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar en el textbox el resultado de mi procediemiento almacenado seleccionado los combobox?

Tags: c#

[image: Este es el diseño de mi formulario]

**Este es mi procedimiento almacenado en SQL**

*Fundo = Nombre;
Mes = Descripcion*

```
create procedure spSumaDeTodos
@Nombre varchar(50), @Descripcion varchar(50)
as
begin
SELECT SUM(Costo)/(select TipoCambio from Periodo where Periodo.Descripcion = @Descripcion) as Suma 
FROM BDCostos INNER JOIN Periodo ON BDCostos.idPeriodo = Periodo.idPeriodo INNER JOIN Sectores 
ON BDCostos.idSector=Sectores.idSector INNER JOIN Fundo 
ON Sectores.idFundo=Fundo.idFundo
WHERE Fundo.Nombre = @Nombre AND Periodo.Descripcion =@Descripcion
end
go
```

**En la clase de nombre Mantenimiento**

```
 public void SumarFundoMes(string Nombre, string Descripcion)
            {
                SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("spSumaDeTodos", cn);
                da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Nombre;
                da.Parameters.Add("@Descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Descripcion;
                cn.Open();
                da.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
```

**En el formulario**

```
public partial class InformeConsolidado : Form
    {
        Mantenimiento man = new Mantenimiento();
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=hola;Integrated Security=True");
        public InformeConsolidado() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cargarDatos();
            cargaMes();
        }
        public void cargarDatos()
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select idFundo, Nombre from Fundo", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cn.Close();

            DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
            fila["Nombre"] = "Selecciona un Fundo";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);

            cboFundo.ValueMember = "idFundo";
            cboFundo.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
            cboFundo.DataSource = dt;
        }
        public void cargaMes()
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select idPeriodo, Descripcion from Periodo", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cn.Close();

            DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
            fila["Descripcion"] = "Selecciona un Mes";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);

            cboMes.ValueMember = "idPeriodo";
            cboMes.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";
            cboMes.DataSource = dt;
        }
        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             string Nombre = cboFundo.SelectedItem.ToString();
             string Descripcion = cboMes.SelectedItem.ToString();

             try
              {
                  if (Nombre != "Selecciona un Fundo" && Descripcion != "Selecciona un Mes")
                  {
               man.SumarFundoMes(Nombre, Descripcion);
              }
                }
               catch
                {
                MessageBox.Show("Seleccione un Fundo o Descripcion");
              }
        }
```

}
}

Mi pregunta es como podría mostrarme en el *textbox* el resultado de mi procedimiento almacenado, cuando selecciono un *item* de c/u de los *combobox* y le doy click a "Reportar".

Answer (score 1):

Vas a tener que hacer varios cambios en varios lados.

```
public decimal SumarFundoMes(string Nombre, string Descripcion)
{
    SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand("spSumaDeTodos", cn);
    da.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Nombre;
    da.Parameters.Add("@Descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Descripcion;
    cn.Open();
    Decimal value = da.ExecuteScalar();
    cn.Close();
    return Value
}
```

Esta función ahora recupera el primer valor del primer campo de la consulta. desconozco si tu consulta devuelve mas datos que eso, no lo aclaraste. Executenonquery no devuelve valores, solo ejecuta lo que se le pide.

En la función del botón:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Nombre = cboFundo.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string Descripcion = cboMes.SelectedItem.ToString();
    try
    {
        if (Nombre != "Selecciona un Fundo" && Descripcion != "Selecciona un Mes")
        {
             decimal valor = 0;
             if (Decimal.TryParse(man.SumarFundoMes(Nombre, Descripcion).ToString(), out valor))
             {
                  txtSuma.Text = valor.ToString();
             }
             else {
                  txtSuma.Text = 0; //Cero o el valor que tu definas 
             }                 
        }
    }
   catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Seleccione un Fundo o Descripcion");
        }
    }
}
```

En esta ultima se tomo el valor que devuelve SumarFundoMes y se paso al textbox correspondiente

Comment: Gracias por responder, al cambiar lo que me indicas me sale un error de -No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'object' en 'decimal'-. Y lo de TEXTBOXSUMA =  man.SumarFundoMes(Nombre, Descripcion); me muestra otro error similar de 'decimal' a 'TextBox'.

Comment: yo no escribi el codigo exacto que necesitas.. Aclare que no sabia como se llamaba tu textbox, y el primer error es porque tenes que castear el resultado (executenonquery devuelve un object)

Comment: El txt lo he nombrado como 'txtSuma', pero como te lo mencione me sale el error de -No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'decimal' en 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox', disculpa las molestias.

Comment: Ok. Cuando pueda actualizo la respuesta. Pero es txtsuma.value = man.suma....

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de cambiar TEXTBOXSUMA por txtSuma y agregué un TryParse para convertir de Object a Decimal, espero que con eso puedas ejecutarlo correctamente

Comment: excelente, gracias @AlejandroMedina